# In TalkJS, how can I save or load a profile photo for our users if our images are not public?

Tags: chat

How can I save or load a profile photo for our users if our images are not public?

Is there a way where I will just pass a photo URL which could be private but accessible within my network for TalkJS to just load in the message conversations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment in TalkJS it’s not possible to save or load a profile photo for users if the relevant image is not public. The website needs to be able to load the photo.

Here are two possible workarounds you could use:

- One workaround would be to make a [`data:` URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/http/basics_of_http/data_urls) for the images, and set those as the profile photo URLs.
- Another workaround could be that if you are displaying the profile photos on your own site, and if the origin is whitelisted, then you can also whitelist `app.talkjs.com`.